Redirect to Dashboard after Login in React.js - BrowserRouter error
I've got a simple To-Do list written in React, and I'm trying to add login to it. I want to have the login page as the landing page and redirect to the Dashboard after login, but I'm still new to React, so I'm not sure how to accomplish this with useNavigation(). Note: there is no real authentication yet, nor is there any logic to handle wrong or invalid credentials. App compiles but the following error appears in the browser:

useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a  component.

I get that useNavigation() can't be called inside another function, but I'm not sure who to use it properly.
App.js
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import useToken from './useToken';

function App() {
  const {token, setToken} = useToken();
  
  if(!token) {
    return <Login setToken={setToken} />
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Login.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Login.css';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

async function loginUser(credentials) {
 return fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
 })
   .then(data => data.json())
}

export default function Login({ setToken }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [username, setUserName] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const token = await loginUser({
      username,
      password
    });
    if(token) {
      setToken(token);
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  return(
    <div className="login-wrapper">
      <h1>Please Log In</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <p>Username</p>
          <input type="text" onChange={e => setUserName(e.target.value)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          <p>Password</p>
          <input type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
        </label>
        <div>
          <button type="login">Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

Login.propTypes = {
  setToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

UPDATE 1:
I made a change in index.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const DATA = [
  {id: "todo-0", name: "Make bed", completed: true},
  {id: "todo-1", name: "Fold laundry", completed: false},
  {id: "todo-2", name: "Brush teeth", completed: false}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App tasks={DATA} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

I replaced React.StrictMode with BrowserRouter like so:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const DATA = [
  {id: "todo-0", name: "Make bed", completed: true},
  {id: "todo-1", name: "Fold laundry", completed: false},
  {id: "todo-2", name: "Brush teeth", completed: false}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App tasks={DATA} />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

I removed BrowserRouter from App.js, so this is what it looks like now:
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );

I get the login page after starting the app, but as soon as I try to log in, I get a new error in the browser:

tasks is undefined
Dashboard@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:215:20

Again, I get no compiler errors.
Dashboard.js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
import FilterButton from "./FilterButton";
import Todo from "./Todo";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

function usePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
  }
  
  const FILTER_MAP = {
    All: () => true,
    Active: (task) => !task.completed,
    Completed: (task) => task.completed
  };
  
  const FILTER_NAMES = Object.keys(FILTER_MAP);

export default function Dashboard(props) {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(props.tasks);
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('All');

    function addTask(name) {
        const newTask = { id: `todo-${nanoid()}`, name, completed: false };
        setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
      }
    
      function toggleTaskCompleted(id) {
        const updatedTasks = tasks.map((task) => {
          // if this task has the same ID as the edited task
          if (id === task.id) {
            // use object spread to make a new object
            // whose `completed` prop has been inverted
            return {...task, completed: !task.completed}
          }
          return task;
        });
        setTasks(updatedTasks);
      }
    
      function deleteTask(id) {
        const remainingTasks = tasks.filter((task) => id !== task.id);
        setTasks(remainingTasks);
      }
    
      function editTask(id, newName) {
        const editedTaskList = tasks.map((task) => {
        // if this task has the same ID as the edited task
          if (id === task.id) {
            //
            return {...task, name: newName}
          }
          return task;
        });
        setTasks(editedTaskList);
      }  
    
      const taskList = tasks.filter(FILTER_MAP[filter]).map((task) => (
        <Todo
          id={task.id}
          name={task.name}
          completed={task.completed}
          key={task.id}
          toggleTaskCompleted={toggleTaskCompleted}
          deleteTask={deleteTask}
          editTask={editTask}/>
      ));
      
      
      const filterList = FILTER_NAMES.map((name) => (
        <FilterButton
          key={name}
          name={name}
          isPressed={name === filter}
          setFilter={setFilter}
        />
      ));
    
      const tasksNoun = taskList.length !== 1 ? 'tasks' : 'task';
      const headingText = `${taskList.length} ${tasksNoun}`;
      const listHeadingRef = useRef(null);
      const prevTaskLength = usePrevious(tasks.length);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (tasks.length - prevTaskLength === -1) {
          listHeadingRef.current.focus();
        }
      }, [tasks.length, prevTaskLength]);

    return(
        <div className="todoapp stack-large">
        <h1>Trevor's ToDo List</h1>
            <Form addTask={addTask} />
            <div className="filters btn-group stack-exception">
                {filterList}
            </div>
            <h2 id="list-heading" tabIndex="-1" ref={listHeadingRef}>
                {headingText}
            </h2>
            <ul className="todo-list stack-large stack-exception" aria-labelledby="list-heading" >
                {taskList}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}


Use the useNavigate hook to effect an imperative navigation action. I feel your question will eventually lead you to How to create a protected route with React-Router-DOM.

I see no issue with where and how you are using the useNavigate hook in the code you've updated. See if you can create a running Codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

I have never used Codesandbox, but I will try. I have kept tinkering, and I have an update.

Solution - useNavigate() Hook
React Router Dom provides a hook named useNavigate() which can be used to redirect to another path.
Here is how can you use it.
Declaring the hook
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Login({ setToken }) {
    ----your code here---
    const navigate = useNavigate()
}

Using the hook
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const token = await loginUser({
      username,
      password
    });

    // check if authenticated

    if(token){

        setToken(token);
        
        // navigate to '/dashboard'
        navigate('/dashboard')
    }
}


I'm getting an error in the browser: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a  component.
